# Using multiple bone rigged objects for character animations (Unity2D 8 directions isometric movement)

Tags: unity, animation

my partner made the animations for our character in a 2d isometric game built with unity. He made 5 bone rigged bodies (each made of several sprites) and each has its own animator. He then made 1 animation for each body (N, NE, E, SE, S) and mirrored 3 of them (NE, E, SE) to make the missing ones. We have 8 animations for Idle and 8 for moving, one for each direction. How can i link animations from different animators on player movement input (checking for vertical/horizontal input)? Any help would be really appreciated. The bodies have been rigged on unity but im thinking of getting Spine2D, would it be more helpfull to make an 8 way isometric 2d character animation to implement in unity? Making this with spritesheets was really easy but with the different rigged bodies im kinda in the blue here... cheers!

Comment: It's unclear to me what the different bodies here represent. Can you show us?

Comment: Our player moves in 8 directions. For each direction we made a bone rigged sprite character in unity. Every character has its own animator. So when i want to move for example... North west direction, i would have to switch my players sprite and also animator to choose the correct animations. Im looking for a way to use multiple animators and thus respective sprites for the same player movement animation system (sorry i will provide pics as soon as i can thanks for your time :) )

Comment: I'd recommend using one animator for all 8 directions, rather than coordinating multiple copies.

Comment: How would i go about putting the different facing sprites (remember each direction has its own bone system to make the animations) in the same animator?

Comment: The same way you put multiple sprites in any animator. Then you can just toggle their visibility off when not facing in that direction, using eg. an animation layer.